# Installing Sonnet with Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Just wondering if there is any way to install Deep Mind's Sonnet library with Anaconda yet. On the site it says to use conda install -c hcc dm-sonnet, however that provides a PackageNotFoundError because this method only works on Linux distributions and I'm currently using macOS.

If this is not possible and I use pip to install the Sonnet package, will this produce any errors since I use conda as my main distribution system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda comes with it's own pip and packages installed with that will work fine together with the rest of your anaconda environment. Try to run `which pip` and see if that is in the anaconda path.
There can be some issues if the dependencies required from pip doesn't match up with what is required in your anaconda environment. However you can always pip uninstall if it breaks anything.